# How to use temporary variable in Update query?

Tags: mysql, sql

How can I set a variable while doing an Update statement?

I can't seem to figure out the syntax. I am using this `@tp` variable for holding calculated result and it will be used in `when` condition.

I want something like this:

```
UPDATE users IU
INNER JOIN activity_stats DAS
    ON (IU.user_id=DAS.for_user_id), set
    @tp:= IU.total_subscription_time - (unix_timestamp()- IU.start_date),
    IU.time_period_left = CASE WHEN @tp > 0 THEN @tp ELSE 0 END,
    IU.used_time = (unix_timestamp() - IU.start_date),
    IU.status = CASE WHEN @tp > 0 THEN 'A' ELSE 'I' END,
    DAS.total_time_used = DAS.total_time_used + IU.used_time 
WHERE IU.time_period_left > 0
  AND IU.status='A'
```

but it's saying the syntax is wrong:
[image: but it's saying the syntax is wrong]

Comment: Edit your question and provide (1) sample data; (2) desired results; (3) a clear explanation of the logic.

Comment: Have you tried leaving out the `set` before your assignment?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this?

```
  UPDATE users IU
INNER JOIN activity_stats DAS
    ON (IU.user_id=DAS.for_user_id), 
    IU.time_period_left = CASE WHEN (IU.total_subscription_time - (unix_timestamp()- IU.start_date)) > 0 THEN 
                        (IU.total_subscription_time - (unix_timestamp()- IU.start_date))  ELSE 0 END,
    IU.used_time = (unix_timestamp() - IU.start_date),
    IU.status = CASE WHEN (IU.total_subscription_time - (unix_timestamp()- IU.start_date)) > 0 THEN 'A' ELSE 'I' END,
    DAS.total_time_used = DAS.total_time_used + IU.used_time 
WHERE IU.time_period_left > 0
  AND IU.status='A'
```

Comment: Thanks @Madhivanan  can we write this query without using extra sub query (select), as i want to run this query in every one minute and this query update my all records in both tables (user and activity_stats).

Comment: I think you can use the expression itself in place of variable. See my edited reply